# Database compression issue in Azure DevOps server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, data-migration, azure-devops-server-2020, azure-devops-services

Actually my database size was around 1.3tb, where I deleted some unnecessary files, builds, pipelines from the database through sql queries method in which my database is now reduced to 160GB in azure devops server, but still i am able to see the database size is 1.3 tb only.

so, could you please guide me how to overcome this issue and get my latest DB size i.e .160GB (after deleting some unnecessary files, builds, pipelines)

Comment: Database files (in SQL Server) don't become smaller after you delete data from it; that is by design. One benefit of this is to avoid fragmentation. As a result after you deleted the data, the database has "free space", but the actual database files themselves are the same size. As a result the database data will grow but the file itself will not. You *can* make the file smaller too, using shrinking, but with such a change in size I would expect fragmentation, which could significantly effect the performance of the database. If you don't "need" to space back, don't shrink.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.